# Triggering checkboxes and divs by prefix

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a map that contains a number of regions with classes such as 'region-one', 'region-two' etc.
Each of these have a corresponding checkbox with classes such as 'toggle-region-one', 'toggle-region-two'.

Clicking on each region or its checkbox will add an 'active' class. I achieve this with the below code:

```
$(function(){
  $("#toggle-region-one").change(function() {
    $("#region-one").toggleClass("active", this.checked)
  }).change();
});

$('#region-one').on('click', function() {
    $('#toggle-region-one').trigger('click');
});
```

I am adding more regions to the map and I do not want to repeat this same code again for each one. Is it possible to replace each class in the jQuery so that it uses the prefixes "region-" and "toggle-"?

So that when any region that starts with "region-" is clicked, the corresponding checkbox that begins with "toggle-" will also be checked?

I have also tried this but it selects all regions/checkboxes

```
$('div[id^="region-"]').on('click', function() {
    $('input:checkbox[id^=toggle-]').trigger('click');
});

$(function(){
  $('input:checkbox[id^=toggle-]').change(function() {
    $('div[id^="region-"]').toggleClass("active", this.checked)
  }).change();
});
```

I have set up a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvj6328m/1/) here.

Comment: Why you don't add classes with `region`/`toggle`? Then you can act on classes instead of prefixes of ID's. That's why you have classes

Comment: `id^=region-` means all id start with `region`. So why  it's happen. Please try to under stand your code.

Answer (score 1):

Without your html code, i suppose classes `region-...` are on a tag div, and classes `toggle-region-...` are on tag input.

You could resolve your problem with the function [.index](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
// this function toggles the class active to the corresponding region
// following the checkbow clicked
$("input[class*=toggle-region-]).on("change", function(){
  var index = $("div[class^=toggle-region-]).index(this);
  $("div[class*=region-]).eq(index).toggleClass('active');
});

// this function is checking the corresponding checkbox
// following the region clicked
$("div[class*=region-]).on("click", function(){
  // i dunno if you want toggle active class in this case 
  // when you clicked region, but its easy to add...
  var index = $("div[class*=region-]).index(this);
  $("input[class*=toggle-region-]).eq(index).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use wildcard with global variable like below.

```
var id1 = ""; //Get checkbox ID
var id2 = ""; // Get Div ID

$(function() {
  $('[id^="toggle-region"]').change(function() {
    id1 = $(this).attr("id");
    id2 = id1.substring(id1.indexOf('-') + 1);
    $("#" + id2).toggleClass("active", this.checked)
  }).change();
});

$("#" + id2).on('click', function() {
  $("#" + id1).trigger('click');
});
```

```js
var id1 = "";
var id2 = "";
$('[id^="toggle-region"]').change(function() {
  id1 = $(this).attr("id");
  id2 = id1.substring(id1.indexOf('-') + 1);

  $("#" + id2).toggleClass("active", this.checked)
}).change();


$("#" + id2).on('click', function() {
  $("#" + id1).trigger('click');
});
```

```css
#region-one,
#region-two,
#region-three {
  background-color: #666;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#map .active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map">
  <div id="region-one"></div>
  <div id="region-two"></div>
  <div id="region-three"></div>
</div>


<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="region" value="region-one" id="toggle-region-one"><label for="toggle-region-one">Region one</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="region" value="region-two" id="toggle-region-two"><label for="toggle-region-two">Region two</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="region" value="region-three" id="toggle-region-three"><label for="toggle-region-three">Region three</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

And this is my solution in vanilla `javascript`. The solution uses the `forEach()` method. And also the `toggle()` method to remove the class when the checkbox is unchecked. I opened your css and html.

```js
var region = document.querySelectorAll('.region');
var checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('ul input');
        
Array.from(checkbox).forEach(function(checkboxArray, i) {
    checkboxArray.addEventListener('click', function() {
      region[i].classList.toggle('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.region {
  background-color: #777;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="map">
  <div class="region" id="one"></div>
  <div class="region" id="two"></div>
  <div class="region" id="three"></div>
  <div class="region" id="four"></div>
  <div class="region" id="five"></div>
  <div class="region" id="six"></div>
  <div class="region" id="seven"></div>
</div>

<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="region" value="region-one" id="toggle-region-one"><label for="toggle-region-one">Region one</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="region" value="region-two" id="toggle-region-two"><label for="toggle-region-two">Region two</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="region" value="region-three" id="toggle-region-three"><label for="toggle-region-three">Region three</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="region" value="region-four" id="toggle-region-four"><label for="toggle-region-four">Region four</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="region" value="region-five" id="toggle-region-five"><label for="toggle-region-five">Region five</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="region" value="region-six" id="toggle-region-six"><label for="toggle-region-six">Region six</label></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="region" value="region-seven" id="toggle-region-seven"><label for="toggle-region-seven">Region seven</label></li>
</ul>
```